# False positive "Undefined error" when compiling scss in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

I import partials into a `global.scss` file with: `@import "userbar;"`.  The userbar file is named `_userbar.scss`.

Within `_userbar.scss`, I have this:

```
@import media all and (min-width: $break-narrow)
```

`$break-narrow` is defined in `_vars.scss`, which is imported at the very top of `global.scss`.

When editing `_userbar.scss` in ST2 I get the error `Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: $break-narrow.`.  Everything builds fine - my generated `global.css` has the changes that I would expect it to have - but this error is annoying.

I am using [Sass Build](https://github.com/jaumefontal/SASS-Build-SublimeText2) installed via the Package manager

Comment: do you have other variables in the exact same situation - defined in `_vars.scss` and used in `_userbar.scss`? If not, try making one and see if the build chokes on that one too.

Comment: Meant to come back for that exact reason @MattDMo - there are others, `$gray`, and `$break-large`.  I think it may be due to finding an error, throwing it, and not proceeding with further checking.  I think this is a config issue with my .sublime-project file, and I think I may be close to resolving but want to do some more testing before posting.